# If $row[MyVar] == 'y' echo 'something' possible?

Tags: php, if-statement

HTML :

```
<input class="no-check-border-win" type="checkbox" name="Parking" value="y" [parking] 
/>Parking<br />
```

[my_var] :

```
 if ($_POST['Parking']=='y') echo 'checked="checked"';
```

$var :

```
$Parking = $_POST[Parking]?'y':'n';
```

PHP Page data form collection:

```
echo 'Parking: '.$row[Parking].'<br />';
```

*This code is fine* and display me an 'y' or 'n' if checkbox is checked or not //
**Now...I want to also display: **image1** if checkbox is checked **image2** if unchecked.

**I was thinking about something like this**

```
if isset( $Parking == "y" ) {
echo '<img src="1" border=0>';
}
else '<img src="2" border=0>';
```

Comment: and your problem is what... beyond the totally broken isset call? You cannot isset() on the result of a truth test.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code you want to use is the code you included at the bottom of your question, you should do something like this:

```
if($Parking == "y") {
echo '<img src="1" border=0>';
}
else{
echo '<img src="2" border=0>';
}
```

Is that what you wanted to do?
Or maybe you wanted to check if `$Parking` was set?
To check if `$Parking` was set, you can do this:

```
if(isset($parking)){
//yes it is set!
}
if(!isset($parking)){
//no it is not set
}
```

Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. If set on the result page it does't work. If I need to set it on the form page how do I output it on the result page?

Comment: @Olasz would you mind showing the code that you have on the result page so that I can help? Thanks!

Comment: sorry: **Yr script works perfect** if set in the form page and displays me the right icons:) In the result page not, but it is a good start point as script is valid and works fine. Just now I have to check how to output it on needed pages.